# Count # of Cookie Chocolate Chips

Tags: code-golf, image-processing, counting

Note: this is my first post here.

## The Challenge

The challenge is to count the number of chocolate chips in a cookie. A cookie in this case is a circle with dots (the chips) in it. Given any square cartoon image of this cookie, you are to write a bot that counts and outputs the number of chocolate chips.

## Rules

- Has to take in an image type of png.
- It has to be able to take in any file size, as long as it is square.
- It has to be able to handle both color and B&W images.
- Output can be in any  human-understandable form.
- The circle will be filled with color and will have an outline.
- Chips will all be the same size and color.
- There is only one cookie in the image
- Chocolate chips may be irregularly spaced, but are perfect circles.
- You can use a library.
- There is nothing in the image except the cookie and the chocolate chips.
  -All other cookies will look like the example images.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); the shortest code gets accepted.

## Examples

[Cookie 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCV1A.png) => `8` or `1000` (binary)
[Cookie 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n7AY.png) => `8` or `1000` (binary)
[Cookie 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbZx6.png) => `10` or `1010` (binary)
[Cookie 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8jTo.png) => `7` or `0111` (binary)

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG! Please provide some sample cases and consider simplifying the input so it may be more objectively scored (it may be a bit complex to take *any* kind of hairbrush image - consider creating a criteria).

Comment: Please add example images

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG! Currently this question is lacking quite a few details; image-processing challenges need specifications to be objectively scored. Additionally, you are missing a few details; can the bristles be different sizes? How small can they get? Will there be things other than bristles? I would recommend looking at Wheat Wizard's advice and posting in the Sandbox first to get feedback without the risk of losing reputation or getting the answer closed. So sorry, but I voted this to be closed, which means that it's now on hold. Better luck next time, and check out the Sandbox!

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I am working on them right now. I understand your flag and agree with it. Please take it off when I have posted the images, though...

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I fixed these things.

Comment: I still see references to bristles. Your cleanup is not complete.

Comment: This question has been reopened.

Comment: Are the chocolate chips always the same size?

Comment: @AnthonyPham yes

Comment: Anyone going to try something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mathematica 134 Bytes

```
Max@ComponentMeasurements[ArrayComponents[ImageData@ColorQuantize[RemoveAlphaChannel[#,White],4,Dithering->False],2],"Holes"][[All,2]]&
```

Usage (applied to .png images)

```
%/@cookies
```

Output:

```
{8,8,10,7}
```

Here's the code to bring in the cookie examples:

```
cookieURLs={"https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCV1A.png","https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n7AY.png","https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbZx6.png","https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8jTo.png"};
cookies=Import/@cookieURLs;
```

I'm sure this can be shortened, but I think it's fairly bullet-proof as is. The original images have many more colors than the eye can see.

Here are the original cookies:

[image: cookieout.gif]

Here are the cookies after cleanup to get them into a 4 component array:

```
ArrayPlot[ArrayComponents[ImageData@ColorQuantize[RemoveAlphaChannel[#,White],4,Dithering->False],2]]&/@cookies//Row
```

[image: cookieout2]

After that, all is needed is to use `ComponentMeasurements` to count holes.
This will always report at least 1.  You could have one really big chocolate chip filling the cookie border, so the 0 or 1 case will always be ambiguous.

Comment: Awesome! Can you provide a link so anyone can run it online?